# How do I make this function take arbitrary strings?

Tags: c, string, bubble-sort

So basically, right now, this function can only take 9 words with 10 characters each. How do i make it so that it can take an `arbitrary` amount of `words` and `characters` and sort them accordingly in alphabetical order?

```
int sortText(){ 
  char name[10][9], tname[10][9], temp[10];
  int i, j, n;

  printf("Enter the amount of words you want to sort (max 9):");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter %d words: ",n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      scanf("%s", name[i]);
      strcpy(tname[i], name[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++){
      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
          if (strcmp(name[i], name[j]) > 0){
              strcpy(temp, name[i]);
              strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
              strcpy(name[j], temp);
          }
      }
  }
  printf("\n------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("%-3s %4s %11s\n", "Input","|", "Output");
  printf("------------------------------------------\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      printf("%s\t\t%s\n", tname[i], name[i]);
  }
  printf("------------------------------------------\n");
  }
```

Comment: No, it can take 10 words with 8 characters each (plus the string terminator).

Comment: You'll need to store the strings as char pointers in an dynamically allocated array. Then you can sort the `char *` items within the array. That way, the strings and the array can be of any length.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, how would you suggest i accomplish this? I've only programmed C with static values before and not arbitrary lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems, that each needs to be solved separately, but they can still be solved in a *similar* way, namely using dynamic memory allocations and more importantly *reallocation*.

There are two important aspects to remember here, and the first is that a string is an array of characters (with a special terminating character) and that you can have a pointer to an array located anywhere in memory.

If we start with the data-types and how you should store your strings, what you want is an array of arrays, much like you have right now, but allocated dynamically which means you want an array of pointers (to the strings), but since the array of string also needs to be dynamic you need a pointer to an array which contains pointers to other arrays, i.e. a pointer to a pointer to `char`: `char **`.

Now when we know what data-type to use, lets think about how to allocate it. To allocate space for a single string in your array, you allocate one `char *` using the [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function:

```
char **strings = malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
```

That was the simple part. Now before we start reading the actual string, lets think about how to add a new string to your collection: This is done by *reallocating* the array of strings you have, using the [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function:

```
char **temp_strings = realloc(strings, current_count + 1 * sizeof(char *));
if (temp_string == NULL)
{
    // Allocation failed, handle error appropriately
}
strings = temp_strings;
++current_count;
```

Here the variable `current_count` is the current length of the array of strings, it should be initially initialized to `1` (as we only have a single string in the array).

Now for the reading of the actual strings, and this is a little more complicated since we actually can't read whole strings (since we don't know how long each line is). Instead we read one character at a time, and end when we hit a newline. We also need to reallocate the string for each character.

Maybe something like this:

```
int ch;
char *s = NULL;
size_t current_length = 0;  // Current length of string

while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '\n')
        break;  // Newline, done with the current string

    if (s == NULL)
    {
        s = malloc(2);  // Allocate two character: One for c and one for the terminator
    }
    else
    {
        // The current length is not including the terminator
        // that's why we add two characters
        char *temp_s = realloc(s, current_length + 2);
        if (temp_s == NULL)
        {
            // Handle error
        }
        s = temp_s;
    }

    s[current_length++] = c;
    s[current_length] = '\0';  // Terminate as a string
}

if (s != NULL)
{
    // "Add" the string to the array of strings
    strings[current_count] = s;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback. however, when i try to implement your code, it generates a lot of errors. Märkte att du var svensk när jag gick in på din profil. Hur skulle du föreslå att jag sammansatte våra lösningar in till en? :) mvh joel.

Comment: @Joel Lugnt på jobbet (quiet at work) so I made a complete program for you to read and test: http://ideone.com/s7yWQ8

Comment: @Joel Well I didn't say it would solve youw whole program. Once you've read the input you have to sort it yourself (a simply bubble-sort like you already have should work fine), just instead of doing `strcpy` on the string you copy the *pointers*. And as you can see I pass `stdin` to the function, using a `FILE*` makes the functions more generic, it can read from any standard input stream like the standard input stream. At least the program gives you functions to read arbitrary number of string of arbitrary length, which seemed like your biggest problem.

Comment: thanks for the help once again Joachim. However, I feel like this is a bit too much of stuff I haven't learned yet so I don't feel comfortable with the code as of now. Do you think another solution for my issue is by using getline() and malloc / calloc the size of the inputted string? Because that is the only method I would feel comfortable with using with my current knowledge. 
Would you recommend using this method or is your way the best solution? Cheers.

Comment: @Joel Do you mean [this `getline` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)? Then it would simplify the whole reading dynamic lines because `getline` will do that for you. Then you only have to allocate/reallocate the array of strings. Or if you know how many strings you will read then you can use a fixed-sized array of character pointers.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did at first, but let's say i gave the array 200 places, and the next time i ran the program i needed 201 places. anyhow, thanks for your solution, i'll try to figure out what all the steps are doing even tho it's a bit above what's expected for the assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

For C only you should use char pointer located dynamic.
You can make list by implement a linked list. Then strcmp still work well.
See about linked list here:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html